# Javascript Async calls unrelated callback in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

When using a third party library that doesn't depend on the `async` library, somehow handling an error in the results callback calls an arbitrary callback inside one of the parallel tasks.

eg.

```
var async = require('async'),
    bloomjs = require('bloom-js');
var client = new bloomjs.Client({url: "http://localhost:3005/api"});

async.parallel([function (cb) {
  console.log('callback1');
  client.find('usgov.hhs.npi', '1558490003', function (err, results) {
    console.log('callback2');
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(results);
  });
}], function (err, results) {
  console.log('callback3');
  throw "hello";
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
  console.dir(results);
});
```

generates the output

```
callback1
callback2
callback3
callback2

/Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:30
            if (called) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                              ^
Error: Callback was already called.
    at /Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:30:31
    at /Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:21
    at /Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:575:34
    at /Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/demo.js:9:21
    at /Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/bloom-js/src/bloom.js:117:18
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/untoldone/Source/async-demo/node_modules/bloom-js/src/bloom.js:219:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

It seems the callback2 is somehow being used to handle an exception in callback3. But given `bloomjs` never uses the `async` library, I have no idea how this is possible. Thoughts?

Comment: You're throwing an error while in the `client.find` callback. `bloomjs` probably has a `catch` around the call to the callback that calls it again with an error indication.

Comment: It might be happening in one of the two lines where you return your err variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that inside `bloomjs.Client.find`, the callback code contains something like this:

```
try {
    callback(false, result);
} catch (e) {
    callback(e, result);
}
```

So when your callback throws the `hello` error, this gets caught by the above code, and re-calls the `client.find` callback. This would again call `cb()`, but `async.js` detects this loop and signals its own error.